# DirectXCollision.h missing

Tags: directx, directx10

I am using DirectX10, June release and I am trying to

```
#include <DirectXCollision.h>
```

so that I can use the bounding objects, however it does not seem to be there. Am I missing something basic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That header is not part of D3D10 itself, but rather part of the [DirectXMath library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418725%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the [Windows 8 Developer Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516).

Comment: meaning? I can include it with another file? or it's documentation on something that hasn't been released yet? Is there another boundingVolume class I can use or should I just write my own?

Comment: Meaning that you need the Windows 8 Preview SDK to use that header and the functionality it provides. You may be able to get similar functionality from the classic D3DX API -- for example, [this function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172713%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) -- but you can't use DirectXMath with just the June SDK. You may be better off writing your own, depending on your needs, which you have not described.

Comment: my needs are for bounding spheres, boxes and rays.